# Android emulator runs ok, device quits at onCreate()

Tags: android, android-emulator

As above in the title, emulator runs fine, but the device quits when running `onCreate()`.

The following is the Exception.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompat
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.installViewFactory(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:812)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:57)
myApp.app.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
```

What must I do to solve this?

The following lines are present in the gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
```

The following is the code for onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //this line causes the Error
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ServiceClient.currentActivity = this;
        initialise();
    }catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(Misc.getStackTrace(e));
    }catch(Error e){
System.out.println(Misc.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your onCreate() code.

Comment: The error is probably on `setContentView`, not `super.onCreate`. There's something wrong when inflating your `activity_main` layout. What's your minimum SDK (in your manifest)?

Comment: Minimum is 16, what should I set it to?